# No AndroidManifest.xml file found in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, react-native, visual-studio-code

I want to get my location's latitude and longitude. But there is no androidManifest.xml file in my project which I have created in Visual Studio Code.

How it can be solved?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: How exactly did you create the project? Note that VS Code is "just" an IDE, basically a text editor. react-native projects are not created "with" VS Code.

Comment: I created a project with (expo init projectname) through the terminal of visual studio code.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml file does not exist in Expo managed projects. It only exist in bare React Native project.

You can eject your Expo project or create a new project if the AndroidManifest file is important to you. Otherwise, look for alternative for Expo.